# How to deal with WindowServer kernel panics, three NVIDIA-related KEXTs in the backtrace, whilst using Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, google-chrome, kernel-panic

I have a MacBook Pro (MacBookPro6,2) running OS X 10.7.5.

Once every few days, on average, my screen goes black and it stops responding. Before these incidents I'm mainly browsing, random web pages with Google Chrome.

The keyboard remains lit but no sounds, no response to the keyboard, etc.… I have to force a shut down (press and hold the power button) to get it going again, and when I do, I am presented with an problem report dialog (kernel panic details below).

Might it be an NVIDIA problem?

What can I do about this?

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  110174 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          2
Anonymous UUID:                    A4CC6A2C-98FE-4CF5-9C39-66F22DB910F5

Sun Nov  4 08:32:54 2012
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f80966007): NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff809fccd000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P2/4
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff807c56b280 : 0xffffff8000220792 
0xffffff807c56b300 : 0xffffff7f80966007 
0xffffff807c56b390 : 0xffffff7f80a5eb83 
0xffffff807c56b3f0 : 0xffffff7f80a5ebf7 
0xffffff807c56b460 : 0xffffff7f80d60855 
0xffffff807c56b5a0 : 0xffffff7f80a82ddd 
0xffffff807c56b5d0 : 0xffffff7f8096fd6a 
0xffffff807c56b680 : 0xffffff7f8096b43c 
0xffffff807c56b870 : 0xffffff7f8096cf6e 
0xffffff807c56b950 : 0xffffff7f81e9064e 
0xffffff807c56b990 : 0xffffff7f81ea73d8 
0xffffff807c56b9b0 : 0xffffff7f81ec53a2 
0xffffff807c56b9f0 : 0xffffff7f81ec5643 
0xffffff807c56ba30 : 0xffffff7f81eab329 
0xffffff807c56ba80 : 0xffffff7f81e5f70b 
0xffffff807c56bb10 : 0xffffff7f81e5da09 
0xffffff807c56bb40 : 0xffffff7f81e64221 
0xffffff807c56bb70 : 0xffffff800065645d 
0xffffff807c56bbe0 : 0xffffff80006567fc 
0xffffff807c56bc40 : 0xffffff8000656fbb 
0xffffff807c56bd80 : 0xffffff80002a3f08 
0xffffff807c56be80 : 0xffffff8000223096 
0xffffff807c56beb0 : 0xffffff80002148a9 
0xffffff807c56bf10 : 0xffffff800021bbd8 
0xffffff807c56bf70 : 0xffffff80002aef10 
0xffffff807c56bfb0 : 0xffffff80002daec3 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.NVDAResman(7.3.2)[97284661-2629-379E-B86B-D388618E8C30]@0xffffff7f808ff000->0xffffff7f80bfafff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7)[5C23D598-58B2-3204-BC03-BC3C0F00BD32]@0xffffff7f80889000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.4)[7C8672C4-8B0D-3CCF-A79A-23C62E90F895]@0xffffff7f808ed000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.4)[D0A1F6BD-E66E-3DD8-9913-A3AB8746F422]@0xffffff7f808b4000
         com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal(7.3.2)[38ACBB3D-4E3C-3883-9A4B-67F15592905F]@0xffffff7f80bfb000->0xffffff7f80f1dfff
            dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(7.3.2)[97284661-2629-379E-B86B-D388618E8C30]@0xffffff7f808ff000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7)[5C23D598-58B2-3204-BC03-BC3C0F00BD32]@0xffffff7f80889000
         com.apple.GeForce(7.3.2)[7E1D7726-416F-3716-ACCB-E1E276E35002]@0xffffff7f81e47000->0xffffff7f81f09fff
            dependency: com.apple.NVDAResman(7.3.2)[97284661-2629-379E-B86B-D388618E8C30]@0xffffff7f808ff000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.4)[7C8672C4-8B0D-3CCF-A79A-23C62E90F895]@0xffffff7f808ed000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.7)[5C23D598-58B2-3204-BC03-BC3C0F00BD32]@0xffffff7f80889000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.4)[D0A1F6BD-E66E-3DD8-9913-A3AB8746F422]@0xffffff7f808b4000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
11G63

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FF3BB088-60A4-349C-92EA-CA649C698CE5
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 27024603453383
last loaded kext at 19349484474949: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.7.2 (addr 0xffffff7f80795000, size 241664)
last unloaded kext at 347604711879: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   5.1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8175f000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  3.2.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  3.2.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 3.2.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 3.2.0
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.75
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 7.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   5.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.8f17
com.apple.GeForce   7.3.2
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.1.33
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.1.33
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.2d6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  227.6
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 227.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  312
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 33
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.2.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.1.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.4b8
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   561.7.22
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 195.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine   1.4
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   195.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.6fc18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.2.5a5
com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal    7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.1.33
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.1.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.NVDAResman    7.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.3d10
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.8f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 230.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.1b1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   420.3
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.4.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.8
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  177.8
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 331.7
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.18
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.5
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.66 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.58f15
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 512 MB
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533642465238432D47372020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533642465238432D47372020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.198.19.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545050B9SA02, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0xfa130000 / 5
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0236, 0xfa120000 / 4
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8218, 0xfa113000 / 6
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: Built-in iSight, apple_vendor_id, 0x8507, 0xfd110000 / 4
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 3
```

Comment: Is there a specific application your running when this error occurs or is it at random?

Comment: mainly just random web browsing, most of the time (using Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so everyone knows, I had to bite the bullet and take it in to be fixed, but as it turns out this was a known fault in my line of Macbook Pros (lucky me) so it was fully fixed with no cost.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it might be the ram or graphics card.

First, you should do the [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1509) and check your hardware out for any issues. Press and hold the D key before the gray startup screen appears. (On some versions it is Command + D)

Next, I would look into this [forum thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3114550?start=0&tstart=0) because most of the users have a similar error. Some report that its a setting that can be changed and others report that apple has replaced all their hardware with the AppleCare Plan.

Good Luck.

---

For grins, if it happens every few days only, why don't you shutdown your laptop each night and start it up each morning?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I will have a go at that. I really hope its not hardware, big inconvenience...

Comment: These are sometimes tricky. Maybe try a different VM host like [VMware Fusion](http://store.vmware.com/store/vmware/pd/productID.165310200/Currency.USD/?src=PaidSearch_Google_eBiz_Fusion_US_Brand) for your guests?

Comment: just an update, I have switched to the integrated graphics, and so far no crashes...

Answer (score 3):

## Google Chrome

At least one version of Google Chrome is known to cause kernel panics on OS X. Amongst open issues for Chromium there are currently [nine matches for *panic NVIDIA*](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=panic%20NVIDIA&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&x=mstone&y=owner&cells=tiles) and [one match for *panic NVDA*](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=panic%20NVDA&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&x=mstone&y=owner&cells=tiles). At least one of the Intel-oriented titles includes discussion of kernel panics with NVIDIA hardware.

### Critically

Google Chrome may report itself as current when in fact it is outdated. Today, for example, 21.0.1180.89 ([stable in August 2012](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/stable-channel-update_30.html)) is reportedly up-to-date –

[image: screenshot of an outdated Google Chrome with a misleading statement]

– but that's not true; I download another copy from Google and find something more recent:

[image: Finder Info for Google Chrome 23.0.1271.64]

### Advice

Use **something other than Google Chrome** to check that Google Chrome is up-to-date.

At the time of writing, [Chrome Releases: Stable updates](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/Stable%20updates) shows [23.0.1271.64 in a post on 2012-11-06](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/stable-channel-release-and-beta-channel.html).

## Third party kernel extensions

In my experience, some types of unexplained panic may be avoided by paying attention to third party KEXTs.

### VirtualBox

Your installation of VirtualBox should be updated – 3.2.0 was [outdated in June 2010](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-3.2).

Even with recent version 4.2.2 of VirtualBox, with NVIDIA hardware in a MacBookPro5,2 I sometimes find kernel panics. For these incidents, not all .panic files point to NVDA or VirtualBox but I have a strong sense that VirtualBox is at least partly contributory to the issues.

(Side note: 4.2.4 at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html … I'll give that a go.)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a Mid 2010 15-inch MacBook Pro, just like myself.

Mid 2010 15-inch MacBooks Pro come with a defective NVIDIA GPU that may cause unexpected restarts, kernel panics, black screens See [Apple's support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4088).